# Why is Cloud9 asking me if I want to Display all * possibilities (y or n)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

Using cloud9 environment and it keeps prompting me:

```
Do you want to display all 2596 possibilities? (y or n)
```

The number changes as I change my environment. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Regardless of whether I hit yes or no, the prompt recurs within seconds.

Comment: Did you press tab twice?

Comment: Perhaps. And, I didn't know about that trick. Though, isn't it still unexpected that it kept prompting? If it happens again, I'll see if TAB-TAB seems to stop the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep prompting"? That message usually appears when you press tab twice to see all completion possibilities and the list of possibilities is too long. Just press `n`.